# Mixed effects model for repeated measures to test for factors that are either constant or dynamic within an individual over time

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am dealing with a rather complicated dataset with repeated measures of the same individuals at various time points (samples were collected at different time points and different number of samples for each individual). I am interested in finding out whether certain factors have an effect on the outcome. Here is a summary of variables involved:

- `constantFactor` -- factor that is the same within an individual over time, e.g. sex, genotype, etc.
- `dynamicFactor` -- factor that can change over time within an individual, e.g. disease status, dietary intake
- `time` -- time points the samples were collected from each individual
- `ID` -- indicator of samples from the same individual
- `outcome` -- outcome of interest

Since the dataset involves repeated measures, I thought that a mixed-effects model could account for that. So I tried to model the data using the `nlme` package in `R`. Here is an example of how I build the model.

`model <- lme(outcome~factor, random=~1|ID, correlation=corCAR1(form=~time|ID))`

(** `factor` can be the `constantFactor` or the `dynamicFactor` above)

There are few points I wish to clarify to see if I am doing things correctly:

1. is it necessary to include the variable `time` in the fixed effect, even though I am only interested in the effect of the `factor`? If so, do I include it as an independent factor: `outcome~factor+time` or as an interaction with my factor of interest: `outcome~factor*time`?
2. if I use the correlation structure argument, is it necessary to put `random=~time|ID` instead of `random=~1|ID`? However, if I do that, I very often end up with the error: `iteration limit reached without convergence (10)`
3. if the outcome does not show time-dependent increase/decrease (the outcome fluctuates randomly over time), is it necessary/useful to use the `corCAR1` structure instead of just `corAR1`?
4. is it right to model the `dynamicFactor` in this way?
5. I find many examples on the internet of how to build mixed-effects models using `lme`, but there isn't much on how to interpret the output or perform model diagnostics, I'd greatly appreciate if any one could briefly explain or point out where I should look up for this.

Insights on any of the questions above are welcomed. Feel free to let me know if there is any thing that needs to be clarified. I thank you for your help in advance.